# how to use spel inline list in thymeleaf th:each tag

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, spring-el

In the [thymeleaf official docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#the-springstandard-dialect), it states

> Use Spring Expression Language (Spring EL or SpEL) as a variable expression language, instead of OGNL. Consequently, all ${...} and *{...} expressions will be evaluated by Spring’s Expression Language engine.

So I have following html code in which `#{1,2,3}` is a spel inline list expression

```
<select>
    <option th:value="${opt}" th:each="opt : ${'#{1,2,3}'}"/>
</select>
```

I hope it can be transformed to

```
<select>
    <option value="1"/>
    <option value="2"/>
    <option value="3"/>
</select>
```

But it was transformed to

```
<select>
    <option value="#{1,2,3}"/>
</select>
```

Why? Thanks in advance!

**Update**

The correct usage is `th:each="opt : ${'#{1,2,3}'}"`

Comment: shouldnt you be using ${1,2,3}, why #{1,2,3}

Comment: @kuhajeyan actually I have tried `${1,2,3}`, but it thrown `Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "1,2,3"`. I use `#{1,2,3}` because of the `@Value(#{...})` usage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
<select>
    <option th:value="${opt}" th:each="opt : ${ {1, 2, 3} }"/>
</select>
```

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-inline-lists

`${'#{1,2,3}'}` evaluates to the string '#{1,2,3}', which is why you get a single `<option>` with value `#{1,2,3}`.  I'm not really sure how the expression `#{1,2,3}` is supposed to represent a list.